# Lavarel4: Logout google using Oauth artdarek

Tags: php, laravel-4, oauth

I just start learning L4, begining with [Oauth by Artdarek](https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel).

I can login using google but i cant find a way to logout by unset Session token or something like that. I already read document on github but just login, no logout example in there.

`Tried Session::flush();` `Auth::logout();` but it is not working.

Using the google logout url works fine but it is logging out all google web apps (gmail etc).

Is there a way to clear google session?

Comment: No just use the providers logout provided by artdarek

Comment: @aldrin27 i did not see it on github or any example via google
https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel#usage
can u give me a link

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to clear your google tokens:

```
$google = OAuth::consumer('Google');
$google->getStorage()->clearAllTokens();
```